# ASP.MVC Permissioning : Is there a way to control partial content ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing an ASP.MVC application and I know you can use authorisation filters on the cotrollers to control access to the pages but I am wondering what is the best approach to do if you want to control access to protected data within partial views.

From what I have read ASP.MVC doesnt offer this level of granularity.

This seems easily enough by adding the user permissions to the model as an attribute and then using a simple factory to decide if the view should be rendered or a blank view be returned.

So far I have

RenderPartial(PartialFactory.IsAllowedToRender("partialName", Model.Security), Model)

and the Factory either returns the view requested or a blank partial view.

Has anyone tried this before or knows why no one does this (apart from the extra effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have done similarly with extension methods for HtmlHelper.

RenderPartialIfExists and so on. No shame in doing this if its something you are going to need frequently.

Doing it without the extensions as you have works as well, but its not as clean to read. Also, consider adding your security information to HttpContext.Current.Items, that way you don't have to pass it into the models all the time, and anything that needs to take advantage of it, helpers, controllers, etc have easy access to it, and you only have to fetch it at the beginning of a request.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  keeping it out the model would be cleaner